# Matrix of Linear Transformation by right multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and let $V$ denote the space of $n$-dimensional row vectors. What is the matrix of the linear operator ‘‘right multiplication by $A$’’ with respect to the standard basis of $V$?

I am not sure where to begin with this problem.

Comment: Hint: it's $A$.

Comment: Actually the Questions are so similar in notation, etc. that I'm going to flag for this one to be merged into the other (linked above).  The OP here has not been active in some time, and the recent Answer below by @MauriceP is worth preserving.

Answer (score 5):

Let $T:V \to V$ be the linear map defined by

$$T(v^T)=v^TA. $$

We want to think of $V$ as an abstract vector space, and express $T$ as a *left* matrix multiplication. In order to do this we use the canonical isomorphism $V \to F^n$ defined by $v \mapsto v^T$. Applying $T$ to the first basis vector $e_1^T$, gives $T(e_1^T)=e_1^TA=R_1(A)=(a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots, a_{1n})$, the first row of $A$, which can also be written as the linear combination $a_{11} e_1^T+a_{12} e_2^T+\dots+a_{1n} e_n^T$. Thus the first column of $[T]$ is the first row of $A$. Continuing in this manner, we get

$$[T]=A^T. $$

Answer (score 0):

It is the function $f:h^T\rightarrow h^TA$ where $h$ is a vector. We choose the basis $e_1^T,\cdots,e_n^T$ where $e_1\cdots,e_n$ is the canonical basis. EDIT: Then the matrix associated to $f$ is $A$ (for every $i$, calculate $f(e_i^T)$ and write the $n$ results row by row).

Comment: The matrix is the transpose of *A*.  See the other answer.