# How do I interpret this matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I interpret the notation $$T(x_1, x_2)=(3x_1, x_1+2x_2)$$
Is this a matrix transformation such that $T(\vec x)=\begin{bmatrix} 3x_1 \\ x_1+2x_2\end{bmatrix}$?

If so, then am I correct to say the matrix must be $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$, so $$T(\vec x)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}; \ T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$$

Comment: This looks good to me

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: It's also helpful to call $T$ a left-multiplication transformation, as there exists right-multiplication transformations: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704745/matrix-of-linear-transformation-by-right-multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give a correct interpretation of the notation. Depending on the context, the underlying vector space may be $\mathbb{F}^2$ for some other field $\mathbb{F}$.

If you use *row* vectors instead, you may write
$$
T(x)=xA
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\;.$$